# Module export callback in NodeJS for Unit Test

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, axios

I have the following piece of code to establish a server connection using axios in my project:

```
    axios.get('/someurl')
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

I am using Jest as a testing framework and I successfully mocked axios, but I have a problem with this then-Function:

```
module.exports = {
  get: function(a)
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    return "abc";
  }
 }
```

However, when running the tests I get the following error message:

> TypeError: _axios2.default.get(...).then is not a function

I must somehow find a way to tell that then exists and is a function. I must do this in the module.exports. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Promises have a `then` function. Your mocked up function needs to return a Promise.

Comment: So no need to mock then itself?

Comment: Right. Just return a Promise from your `get` function.

Comment: return new Promise(function(abc) { console.log("jlk"); })  something like this will replace my actual implementation of then, will it?

Comment: Or just `return Promise.resolve('abc')` if you expect the result to always be successful.

Comment: This is great - how can I pass data to abc?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `'abc'` is a string. You don't pass data to strings. `'abc'` will be `response` in the `then` function.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me alot. Is there any way to wait for the then function to be ready in the unit test?

Comment: The whole point of Promises is that you don't have to worry about when it's ready. If you return a Promise then you'll instantly have access to the `then` function. The `then` callback will be executed whenever the value is ready.

Comment: So this is sequential? No nasty asynchronous-background-bahaviour I can never keep track of?

Comment: None. That's the beauty of Promises. They handle all the nasty asynchronous shenanigans for you.

Comment: Maybe you can summarize your hints in an answer below?

Comment: However thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be expecting the `get` function to return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). That's what the `then` function implies. To do that, you can change your `get` mockup to something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  get: function(a) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      console.log(a);
      console.log(b);
      resolve('abc');
    });
  }
};
```

Or, if you know that it will always be successful, you can simplify it using [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

```
module.exports = {
  get: function(a) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    return Promise.resolve('abc');
  }
};
```

The great thing about Promises is they simplify asynchronous processes. For your mockup, this is all you need but you can use this same process for working with an asynchronous value.

```
module.exports = {
  get: function(a) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // Wait some period of time
      setTimeout(function() {
         // 'abc' + a is passed to the `then` function
         resolve('abc' + a);
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
};
```

Then when you're using this module, it's as simple as:

```
var axios = require('./my-mockup.js');
axios.get('def')
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response); // 'abcdef'
});
```